# Проблема с onListItemClick

Tags: android

У почему то ругается на onListItemClick. Главное - никак не могу понять почему.
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setTitle("New List");

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    adapter = new ItemAdapter();
    adapter.addEnginesNames(names);
    adapter.addEnginesDescriptions(descriptions);
    adapter.addEnginesLogoUrl(logoUrl);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    MyTask mt = new MyTask();
    mt.execute();

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override

        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

                    ...

                    ...

                    ...

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

        });

        public void onListItemClick(ListView l; View v; int position; long id) {

            String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);

            Toast.makeText(this, "olololo" + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

}
```

Подчеркивает onListItemClick и пишет: "void is an invalid type for the variable onListItemClick"
Кроме того, подчеркивает последнюю скобку и пишет: 
"Syntax error on token ")", ; expected"
"Syntax error on token ")", ; expected"

Как с этим бороться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onListItemClick Тут не место.
это отдельный листенер

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
        new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                 }
            }
     );
```

Comment: Подчеркнул первую строчку и..
> Multiple markers at this line
> - The method >setOnItemClickListener(AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) in the type >AdapterView<ListAdapter> is not applicable for the 
>  arguments (new OnItemClickListener(){})
> - OnItemClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: В импорт добавьте класс OnItemClickListener

Comment: а как сделать так, чтобы получать выводить то, что выделил?
Что-то на подобии
>String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
>Toast.makeText(this, "ololo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: а ещё (ListView l; View v; int position; long id) ..тут вообще вместо ";", лучше поставить ","

Answer (score 0):

Привет, как сказал "AndroidDev", onListItemClick - это отдельный листенер. =)
А чтобы получить сообщение с выделенным элементом, используйте getAdapter().getItem().
Т.е. примерно должно выглядеть все так:

```
String[] values = new String[] {
                "String 1",
                "String 2",
                "String 3",
                "String 4",
                "String 5"
        };

        ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.mListView);

        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l)
            {
                // Получение элемента, который был нажат
                Object obj = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(i);
                String item = obj.toString();
                // Выводим сообщение с текстом выбранного элемента
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Вы выбрали: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

За то что после "Copy-Paste" код будет работать не отвечаю! ;)
Писал по памяти, но суть заключается в этом.
Надеюсь данный пример поможет вам.